# bundle all require modules mentioned in nodejs file into one bundle

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, webpack

i have two files imported into the main.js. i want to import all the codes of the required objects or the entire module into the dist.js - mainly bundle all require modules mentioned in nodejs file into one single bundle. anyone knows a simple way of doing it? i am considering webpack for this but any support? open for typescript supported files here

`file1.js`

```
function myfunctionhere() {}
module.exports = {
myfunctionhere
}
```

`file2.js`

```
function myfunctionsecondhere() {}
function myfunctionfunctionhere() {}
module.exports = {
myfunctionsecondhere,
myfunctionfunctionhere
}
```

`main.js`

```
const f1 = require("./file1.js");
const { myfunctionsecondhere } = require("./file2.js");

myfunctionhere()
myfunctionsecondhere()
```

after bundling the file should be like this:

`dist.js`

```
function myfunctionhere() {}
const f1 = { myfunctionhere }

function myfunctionsecondhere() {}

myfunctionhere()
myfunctionsecondhere()
```

i am considering webpack for this but any support? open for typescript supported files here. what options do i have?

Comment: You can use `deno bundle` or `bun bundle`.

Comment: @guest271314 would that work in nodejs venv as well?

Comment: I don't think `node` is shipped with a built-in bundler. `esbuild`, `rollup` and `webpack` are separate technologies. `deno` and `bun` can bundle modules written for Node.js, when `npm:`, and `node:` specifiers are used. E.g., an example of bundling `base64-js`,  `ieee754` and feross/buffer into a single file using `bun` https://gist.github.com/guest271314/08b19ba88c98a465dd09bcd8a04606f6 (though see https://github.com/guest271314/webbundle/blob/browser/index.js#L9), and bundling multiple `.ts` files into a single file https://github.com/guest271314/webbundle/blob/browser/wbn-bundle.js

Comment: no i mean if node inbuilt packages are there in require will it be bundled?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "inbuilt packages". Whether your source code is CommonJS or uses Ecmascript Modules, yes, you can bundle all dependencies into a single script using various JavaScript runtimes and bundling applications.